# Java ObservableList not displaying some values

Tags: java, javafx, arraylist, netbeans, observablelist

I am creating a program to allow landlords to register new tenants with given information. The program writes and reads to a file perfectly, but the problem I am having is that using an ObservableList to populate a TableView won't work with all the data. A tenant extends person and has contact details. The person information displays. But the contact information won't show. Here is my code:

Contact class

```
package entities;

import interfaces.ContactDetailsInterface;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Contact implements ContactDetailsInterface, Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3458489886428771425L;
private String StreetLine;
private String City;
private String Parish;
private String Country;
private String Email;
private String Telephone;
private String TRN;


/**
 * @return the StreetLine
 */
@Override
public String getStreetLine() {
    return StreetLine;
}

/**
 * @param StreetLine the StreetLine to set
 */
@Override
public void setStreetLine(String StreetLine) {
    this.StreetLine = StreetLine;
}

/**
 * @return the City
 */
@Override
public String getCity() {
    return City;
}

/**
 * @param City the City to set
 */
@Override
public void setCity(String City) {
    this.City = City;
}

/**
 * @return the Parish
 */
@Override
public String getParish() {
    return Parish;
}

/**
 * @param Parish the Parish to set
 */
@Override
public void setParish(String Parish) {
    this.Parish = Parish;
}

/**
 * @return the Country
 */
@Override
public String getCountry() {
    return Country;
}

/**
 * @param Country the Country to set
 */
@Override
public void setCountry(String Country) {
    this.Country = Country;
}

/**
 * @return the Email
 */
@Override
public String getEmail() {
    return Email;
}

/**
 * @param Email the Email to set
 */
@Override
public void setEmail(String Email) {
    this.Email = Email;
}

/**
 * @return the Telephone
 */
@Override
public String getTelephone() {
    return Telephone;
}

/**
 * @param Telephone the Telephone to set
 */
@Override
public void setTelephone(String Telephone) {
    this.Telephone = Telephone;
}

@Override
public void setTRN(String trn) {
    this.TRN = trn;
}

@Override
public String getTRN() {
 return TRN; 
}
}
```

Tenant class

```
package entities;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Scanner;
import superclass.Person;

public class Tenant extends Person {

transient SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
transient Calendar calendar;
transient Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

private String dateOfBirth;

//has a
private Contact contact;
private CalculatePayments payment;

private String registra;

public String getDateOfBirth() {
    return dateOfBirth;
}

/**
 * @param dateOfBirth the dateOfBirth to set
 */
public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}

/**
 * @return the contact
 */
public Contact getContact() {
    return contact;
}

/**
 * @param contact the contact to set
 */
public void setContact(Contact contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}

/**
 * @return the payment
 */
public CalculatePayments getPayment() {
    return payment;
}

/**
 * @param payment the payment to set
 */
public void setPayment(CalculatePayments payment) {
    this.payment = payment;
}

/**
 * @return the registrar
 */
public String getRegistra() {
    return registra;
}

/**
 * @param registra the registrar to set
 */
public void setRegistra(String registra) {
    this.registra = registra;
}

}
```

This is my main JavaFX controller that I want to use to populate the TableView

MainPanelController

```
public class MainPanelSceneController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private TableView tenantTable;

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 *
 * @param url
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    //firstName
    TableColumn<Tenant, String> fnColumn = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
    fnColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("FirstName"));

    //lastName
    TableColumn<Tenant, String> lnColumn = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
    lnColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("LastName"));

    //gender
    TableColumn<Tenant, String> genderColumn = new TableColumn<>("Gender");
    genderColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Gender"));

    //dob
    TableColumn<Tenant, String> dobColumn = new TableColumn<>("D.O.B");
    dobColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("dateOfBirth"));

    //Email
    TableColumn<Tenant, String> emailColumn = new TableColumn<>("Email");
    emailColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Tenant, String>("Email"));

    //Phone
    TableColumn<Tenant, String> phoneColumn = new TableColumn<>("Phone #");
    phoneColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Telephone"));

    //TRN
    TableColumn<Tenant, String> TRNColumn = new TableColumn<>("TRN");
    TRNColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("TRN"));

    //Country
    TableColumn<Tenant, String> countryColumn = new TableColumn<>("Country");
    countryColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Country"));

    //Parish
    TableColumn<Tenant, String> parishColumn = new TableColumn<>("Parish");
    parishColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Parish"));

    //City
    TableColumn<Tenant, String> cityColumn = new TableColumn<>("City");
    cityColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("City"));

    //StreetLine
    TableColumn<Tenant, String> streetColumn = new TableColumn<> 
 ("StreeLine");
    streetColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<> 
   ("StreetLine"));

    tenantTable.setItems(getTenants());

    tenantTable.getColumns().addAll(fnColumn, lnColumn, genderColumn,
            dobColumn, emailColumn, TRNColumn,
            phoneColumn, countryColumn, parishColumn,
            cityColumn, streetColumn);
}

private ObservableList<Tenant> getTenants() {
    ObservableList<Tenant> observableList = 
FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    CrudOperations crud = new CrudOperations();
    ArrayList<Tenant> arr = (ArrayList<Tenant>) 
 crud.readObj(Files.TENANT_FILE);
    ListIterator itr = arr.listIterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Tenant t = (Tenant) itr.next();
        observableList.add(t);
    }
    return observableList;
}

}
```

As mentioned before, The observableList only displays information from the person class but it won't display from the contact class. Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

The JavaFX TableView PropertyValueFactory uses reflection to figure out what values to display in table cells.

So when you say:

```java
cityColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("City"));
```

this means cellValueFactory will try to find a method called getCity() to populate cells in the cityColumn.

Since you define your TableColumn as:

```java
TableColumn<Tenant, String> cityColumn = new TableColumn<>("City");
```

The factory looks in the Tenant class for the proper getters to populate the cells. Your problem is that the Tenant class needs to have the getters but the Contact class has them instead. I would suggest adding wrappers for the contact getters to the Tenant class i.e.

```java
public String getCity(){
  return contact.getCity();
}
```

Comment: Is there a simpler way instead of creating addional getters in the tenant class being that the contact class already has them defined. It works but i think its a bit redundant.

Comment: I used that approach because I assumed combining the two classes wasn't an option. I believe that would be the simplest approach. Another approach would be to write your own cell value factory for the elements in the contact class instead of using the `PropertyValueFactory` but either way, you'll need to invoke the getters from the contact class.